# use Ubuntu on mac m1 with an external usb

Tags: usb, mac

i saw many post but all are not recently. i'm searching a guide to run ubuntu on my external usb i tried using that image https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-arm64.iso

and with BalenaEtcher flash it on the usb but when i turn on the pc (with the usb inserted) and press the power button i didn't see the "options" screen where to select ubuntu or macOS. did i miss something.
my finally goal would be have a persistent live usb with ubuntu any idea?

Comment: See https://ubuntuasahi.org/

Comment: You cannot just boot an M1 mac off a USB drive. However, you can dual boot Ubuntu Asahi with MacOS. Note: The Asahi Linux (Arch based) and the Asahi Fedora rimix have better support for Apple silicon hardware. You will find more software running on those distros than Asahi Ubuntu.

Comment: ok thank you but why i can't

Comment: Because Apple does not allow you

Comment: drMAIN: You can't because there is no (U)EFI or BIOS to boot from. Whatever Apple is using to boot is not documented.